# ASP.NET dropdown list

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

rather that populate a dropdown list with a query based on a look-up table, is there a way to have all the records from the look-up as the datasource and simply "go to" the record which would have been found in the query?

thanks

Comment: Is it a question for replacing dropdown with textbox. If so, it depends on the requirements.

Comment: you could cache the results of the query in session/application state as a dictionary, but I'm not sure if that's what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a swag here, but it sounds like you have a collection of objects coming from a database (for the sake of argument let's say Employees) and you want a drop down that will populate with a field from that collection. You could accomplish this with Linq.

```
var emps = from e in db.Employees
           select e;

var ddlSource = emps.Select(x =>
                            new ListItem {
                                              Text = x.LastName + ", " + x.FirstName,
                                              Value =  x.ID
                                         };
```

Then you can bind your DropDownList to the `ddlSource` IQueryable.

Comment: That is exactly what Im doing - when i do the select I get back, say 3 records, where I still want to have all records availablke in the list, but have the 1st 'found' record as the selected item in the list - if that makes sense.....

Comment: That sounds as if you have 2 separate sources. One that matches a filtering criteria and one that is a list of all possibilities. If the number of records isn't too large, you can perform your filter after the original query that way the drop down could be based on the larger query but your filtering result could be applied separately.

Comment: So, it would require 2 datasources then? Other than for example, doing it in MS Access, you would have the dropdown based on a query, then run a DLookup() and the value in the dropdown would be the result of that, but if you clicked the on it the original source is still there?

Answer (score 0):

I guess is that you already have selected item in database and would like it to be selected while populating the dropdown list. Consider below example

View Model

```
public class TestVM 
{
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

In controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
            TestVM objTestVM = new TestVM();            
            objTestVM.Categories = new List<SelectListItem>() { 
                new SelectListItem() { Value="1", Text="Food"},
                new SelectListItem() { Value="2", Text="Movie"}
            };
            objTestVM.CategoryId = 2;//get this value from DB
            return View(objTestVM);
}
```

In View

```
@model MvcApplication4.Models.TestVM
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryId, Model.Categories, "--select--")
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

Now it automatically selects category in the dropdown which is 2 in this case. And if other category is selected and submit the page, new categoryid gets posted back to controller post action.